# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-plugins, wordpress-theming

I was working on a site in WordPress. I don't know why, suddenly its giving the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`. I tried to do almost every thing. Removed the Plugins, Removed the widgest. But it still complaining for it. Due to it my script is not working.

The error is on line 63 of page, which contains

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/hhf/wp-content/plugins/jquery-mega-menu/css/dcjq-mega-menu.css" media="screen" /><script type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */
        (function($){$.fn.s3Slider = function(vars) { var element = this; var timeOut = (vars.timeOut != undefined) ? vars.timeOut : 4000; var current = null; var timeOutFn = null; var faderStat = true; var mOver = false; var items = $("#" + element[0].id + "Content ." + element[0].id + "Image"); var itemsSpan = $("#" + element[0].id + "Content ." + element[0].id + "Image span"); items.each(function(i) { $(items[i]).mouseover(function() { mOver = true; }); $(items[i]).mouseout(function() { mOver = false;fadeElement(true); }); });var fadeElement = function(isMouseOut) { var thisTimeOut = (isMouseOut) ? (timeOut/2) : timeOut; thisTimeOut = (faderStat) ? 10 : thisTimeOut; if(items.length > 0) { timeOutFn = setTimeout(makeSlider, thisTimeOut); } else { console.log("Poof.."); } }; var makeSlider = function() {current = (current != null) ? current : items[(items.length-1)]; var currNo = jQuery.inArray(current, items) + 1; currNo = (currNo == items.length) ? 0 : (currNo - 1); var newMargin = $(element).width() * currNo; if(faderStat == true) { if(!mOver) { $(items[currNo]).fadeIn((timeOut/6), function() { if($(itemsSpan[currNo]).css('bottom') == 0) { $(itemsSpan[currNo]).slideUp((timeOut/6), function() { faderStat = false; current = items[currNo]; if(!mOver) { fadeElement(false); } }); } else { $(itemsSpan[currNo]).slideDown((timeOut/6), function() { faderStat = false; current = items[currNo]; if(!mOver) { fadeElement(false); } }); } }); } } else { if(!mOver) { if($(itemsSpan[currNo]).css('bottom') == 0) { $(itemsSpan[currNo]).slideDown((timeOut/6), function() { $(items[currNo]).fadeOut((timeOut/6), function() { faderStat = true; current = items[(currNo+1)]; if(!mOver) { fadeElement(false); } }); }); } else { $(itemsSpan[currNo]).slideUp((timeOut/6), function() { $(items[currNo]).fadeOut((timeOut/6), function() { faderStat = true; current = items[(currNo+1)]; if(!mOver) { fadeElement(false); } }); }); } } } }        
    makeSlider();};})(jQuery); jQuery(document).ready(function() { jQuery('#slider').s3Slider({ timeOut: 3000 }); });   /* ]]> */</script>
```

I am using jQuery Mega Menu widget plugin.

Comment: I checked there is no element #slider in the page. I think this is the problem. But how can i know why this script is generating in the page.

Comment: I got the error, the generated script on line 63 is trying to access an element #slider, which does not exists on the page, so why its id is not accessible. But i can not found which plugin is generating this script in header.

Comment: Line 63 is the packed JavaScript line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After testing and locating from where it comes, Ultimate Custom Type Manager plugin was generating some scripts, the script file is class-gallery.php so which is generating a script for #slider element which does not exists on the page. Hope some one will fix it soon.

Replaced line **82** of the file **class-gallery.php** with this code

```
$r.="jQuery(document).ready(function() { if(jQuery('#slider').length > 0) { jQuery('#slider').s3Slider({ timeOut: 3000 }); } });";
```

Fixed the problem.